# Pen and Touch option list missing in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Touching a point on a tablet computer running Windows 10 triggers a right click.

I would like to disable this function. My users are handicapped children who should be able to trigger left clicks by touching the screen.

I have found [a tutorial that deals with "Pen and Finger input"](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/disable-or-enable-press-and-hold-for-right-clicking-in-win-10.html). In this tutorial there is a list shown in which you can disable this behaviour:

[image]

In my Windows 10, this list is missing.

In my Windows 10, it only offers "Settings for pen & Windows ink" and "Information about pen und Touch", but not "Settings for pen and Touch":

How would I do this in Windows 10?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This setting is only available in the classic settings. There is another settings menu in Windows 10 ("new Windows Settings UI"). Not all of the classic settings can already be accessed using this new Windows Settings UI.

Also, the linked tutorial states that this is to be found in the "Control Panel", which is the classic settings, not the new Windows Settings UI.